# Flicker in horizontally scrollable Container

Tags: codenameone

I have a horizontally scrollable Container which snaps to a grid by overriding the getGridPosX() method.

Everything works fine except when scrolling by dragging into a position which snaps to the leftmost scroll position there is a flicker which is very notable. That is in the simulator and on IOS, too.

How can I prevent the flicker from happening?

Comment: When I invoke setSmoothScrolling(false) there is no flicker but then the Container also not show scrolling while dragging either.

Comment: Apparently the flicker is caused by the method paintBackgrounds(Graphics aG) of the scrollable Container. It seems strange that paintBackgrounds(Graphics aG) is not called unless the scrollable Container is dragged.

Comment: Clarification: The leftmost scroll position of the horizontally scrollable Container shows the rightmost part of the scrollable Container. Only there and only when finishing the dragging of the Container there is this flicker.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I found the bug.
This was caused by my implementation of getGridPosX(). The value returned was to high which caused the flicker effect.